# Can I use Processing without PApplet to communicate with Arduino in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, arduino

I try to follow [this](http://www.benjohansen.com/arduino-in-eclipse-via-processing) to use [Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29) in Eclipse to communicate with Arduino. But how can I disable the [PApplet](http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html) and use the serial that they provide to communicate with Arduino with standard implementation of [Firmata](http://www.firmata.org/wiki/Main_Page) there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like simply [interfacing with Java](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/Java) ?